# How to get out of man command in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

How to get out of `man command` ?

I pressed `man ls` command in mac and it is lot letting me enter other commands.

As I am learning Linux , so please do not downvote me

Comment: press `q` to exit..

Comment: you want to see list of directory ?

Comment: No downvotes, you can press the letter `q` to quit.  By the way this is not a stack overflow question. I will find a better place in [\[ SuperUser \]](https://superuser.com). Also how about [\[ taking a small tour \]](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and do have a look at what makes a [mcve] here.

Comment: The `man` command invokes your pager, typically the `less` command. `man less` for more information on how `less` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press `q` (like "quit"). To get more info about buttons, press `h` (like "help").

Comment: That should have been a comment. The more important point is that this is not a programming question at all, so need not be answered here.